# Markov algorithm for words of the form $ww$, $w\in \{a,b\}^*$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to construct a Markov algorithm as a set of an ordered rules which will recognize a language $L = \{ww |w \in \{a,b\}*\}$ and give
$$\begin{cases}
Y, \: \text{if given word is in L} \\ 
N, \: otherwise.
\end{cases}$$
Is there a solution for this problem?

UPD. Omitting the formalities Markov Algorithm is an ordered set of rules of the form
$$
\begin{cases}
u_1 \to v_1\\
\vdots \\
u_n \to v_n,
\end{cases}
$$ where $u, v \in \Sigma^*$. Markov algorithm executes the first possible rule in this list, so order is important. For example, next set is a solution of the same problem for a language $L = \{ww^R |w \in \{a,b\}*\}$:
$$
\begin{cases}
Ca \to aC \\
Cb \to bC \\
CC \to T \\
a \to AC \\
b \to BC \\
CT \to N [1][2]\\
AA' \to A'A\\
BA' \to A'B\\
A'A \to e, \text{e is an empty row}\\
A'B \to N \\
AT \to A'[3]\\
BB' \to B'B\\
AB' \to B'A\\
B'B \to e, \text{e is an empty row}\\
B'A \to N \\
BT \to B'[3]\\
G \to Y\\
e \to G
\end{cases}
$$
[1] if after converting all CC's to T there is a C, then word length is odd
[2] In this and similar cases  the string we're working with still has some symbols except for the N, then we will need to clear the output but I've omitted it for brevity. 
[3] check if the string has the same first and last symbols an remove them if yes.

Algorithm implementation for the word abba is:
$$abba \to ABbaCC \to ABbaT \to ABBATT \to ABBA'T \to $$
$$ \to A'ABBT \to BBT \to e \to G \to Y.$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What is a Markov algorithm?  Can you [edit] your question to give a self-contained definition?

Comment: @D.W. added practically useful definition and an example, strict one (in my case) is very toxic and has very little in common with real problems.

Comment: @Nathaniel I have a Turing machine for this problem that works pretty much like [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-turing-machine-language-l-ww-w-01/) and tried to repeat something like that with Markov algorithms. However I don't clearly understand how to find a middle of word in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just some ideas to find the Markov algorithm, I have not tried to write it completely. In particular, I have not determined all priorities.

1. First, it could help to add a left-marker and a right-marker. To do that, just create rule:

> $\varepsilon \to LR$ ($\varepsilon$ is the empty word)

with low priority, and move the right-marker to the right with rules

> $Ra \to aR$
>
> $Rb \to bR$

with high priority.

2. Next, as you said, it is useful to find the middle of the word. You can use the [tortoise and hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) method to do that. The idea is to combine a tortoise $T$ that moves one letter at a time, and a hare $H$ that moves two letters at a time. When the hare reaches the end, the tortoise is in the middle. The following rule creates the tortoise and the hare.

> $L\to LTH$

Now the problem is that the tortoise and the hare must move at the same time. The idea for that is that after a move, the hare sends a "move signal" to the tortoise: for $x, y\in \{a,b\}$, add rules (in this order):

> $xM \to Mx$
>
> $TMx\to xT$
>
> $Hxy \to MxyH$

To check when the hare reach the right side, add rules (with the right priority relatively to the rules above):

> $HxR\to N$ (the length is odd)
>
> $HR \to SR$

3. Now you can reverse the word between the turtle and the right side (to transform $uu$ into $uu^R$). The idea is to **S**witch those letters into variables $A$ or $B$:

> $aS\to AS$
>
> $bS\to BS$

and to reverse the whole thing, for $x\in \{a,b\}$ and $Y\in \{A,B\}$:

> $xY\to Yx$

4. Now we can check if the word is of the form $uu^R$ (I think there is a simpler method than the one you gave, since we know the middle of the string):

> $aTA \to T$
>
> $bTB \to T$
>
> $aTB \to N$
>
> $bTA\to N$

5. Finally, when there is no more letters, the word is accepted:

> $LTSR\to Y$

Note: one might add rules to delete any other letter when there is a $N$.

Comment: In this implementation of tortoise-hare nothing will stop hare to run twice before the tortoise makes its move and vice versa (easy to see on example). I'm thinking about adding special waiting states where hare will wait until the tortoise will move or vice versa, but at this moment i have not finished yet.

Comment: Yes you are right, the priorities are not well-defined. But as I said, those are only ideas!

Comment: @aassegai I edited my answer.